Why is the term 'Accuracy of 1 part in $x$' used?
My question stems from how we measure the accuracy of Caesium clocks. Most Caesium clocks are said to have an accuracy of '$1$ part in $10^{14}$.'
I understand that the terminology means to convey that the clock will edge away from the actual time by no more or less $10^{-14}$, as this answer helped me understand.
My query, then, is simple-why did physicists choose to call it an 'accuracy', instead of an 'inaccuracy' of '$1$ part in $10^{14}$? To me, it seems quite counterintuitive and tough to wrap my head around.
I would appreciate any help on this topic.

Your two expressions are the same. It’s not clear what you’re asking.

@Jagerber48 I'm asking why we call it 'accuracy' at all? It seems to be a strange convention, when 'inaccuracy' is much more convenient to understand.

Calling it "accuracy" is a bit sloppy. A better term is "relative uncertainty". You may also encounter the term "residual precision".

@PM 2Ring My textbook has used both the terms 'uncertainty' and 'accuracy'. Is there a particular reason as to why 'accuracy' is not as acceptable?

It's a bit silly to call it the accuracy when it's actually the inaccuracy. We could say "the clock is accurate to within 1 part in 10^14". I suppose it's a psychological thing. When talking about high precision timekeeping, we want to emphasise the accuracy, not the inaccuracy.

$10^{-14}$ is the relative size of the region within which the measurement apparatus is able to tell the value lies, so it is an accuracy, and $10^{-14}$ is also the amount by which the true value might differ from the measured one, so it is an inaccuracy!
When discussing these issues it is quite common to encounter rather muddled terminology, where something like $\Delta t$ might be called a "precision" but then high precision means low $\Delta t$. A careful author would define their terms more clearly but it is not too big a problem because we all know that high precision or high accuracy means small margin of error. (There is also the fact that precision and accuracy are not necessarily the same but the question is not about that.)
